# Why is the following answer converted into a comment?

Tags: discussion, support

Why is the following answer being converted into a comment?

"See the [FAQ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion)" someone said to me; but in the [FAQ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) I found nothing!

Can anybody express a possible explanation?

--

> Prepositions pose more communication problems for learners of English
>   as well as for native speakers than any other part of speech. In
>   addiction, as "Nortonn S" has demonstrated, there are circumstances
>   when prepostions cause difficulties due to a variety of factors; for
>   instance: "he graduated high school in 2008" or "he graduated from
>   high school in 2008", "he never wrote of it to anyone" or "he wrote
>   nothing about it".
>
> In this light, I hope EL&U continues to assist their members in using
>   prepositions with more precision; especially when ambiguity can arise
>   or when dictionaries are not of great utility to the case.

Comment: The link should be to the Main FAQ. http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion

Comment: @Andrew Leach ... have got again a lotta congratulations for your today 10k result! ... thank you for having punctualized the link! ... but there I found nothing!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Relevant portion: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed"

Comment: It was converted to a comment because it doesn't answer the stated questions there. Why the big deal? It wasn't deleted outright because it was moved to a comment where it belonged (and the intent is preserved).

Answer (score 11):

Your answer on [Questions about prepositions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/questions-about-prepositions) was converted to a comment by Kit because it doesn't really answer the question she asked. The crux of her question was:

> Are "what preposition do I use" questions good questions for this site? If not, how can we make them better?

To which you answered:

> Prepositions pose more communication problems for learners of English as well as for native speakers than any other part of speech. In addiction, as "Nortonn S" has demonstrated, there are circumstances when prepostions cause difficulties due to a variety of factors; for instance: "he graduated high school in 2008" or "he graduated from high school in 2008", "he never wrote of it to anyone" or "he wrote nothing about it".
>
> In this light, I hope EL&U continues to assist their members in using prepositions with more precision; especially when ambiguity can arise or when dictionaries are not of great utility to the case.

While a valid comment, **this doesn't say whether the questions are good questions**. Instead, you correctly point out that a lot of users have issues with this area, and say that you hope EL&U can answer these questions better.

Please note that Kit found your comment to have merit, otherwise she could have deleted it outright.

Comment: Yeah. This. Stop downvoting sim's answer. It's what I would have said had I gotten here first.